# Using translucent png's as textures and fading them OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures, alphablending, translucency

I have some .png files that I'm using as textures for my 2d game quad sprites.

Some of these already have partially transparent pixels in them and I need to be able to display them correctly and fade them in/out.

Initially, I was drawing them with the following blending mode:

```
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This works fine for the textures that are solid to begin with and I can use any value between 1.0f and 0.0f to introduce transparency.  So far so good, but when I try to use png's that already have transparency in them, they won't display correctly (They are too dark and have a dark outline).

I did a lot of research and I found out that I needed to change my blending mode for these types of textures, as the above one wouldn't work properly, so this is now what I have (including my shader)......

**Fragment shader**

```
String strFShader =
"precision mediump float;" +
"varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
"uniform sampler2D u_baseMap;" +
"void main()" +
"{" +
"gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_baseMap, v_texCoords);" +
"gl_FragColor.a *= "+1.0f+";"+  //** Where 1.0f is the amount to blend, with 0.0f being completely transparent and 1.0f being as per the original png file.
 "}";
```

**Code**

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND); 
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

if I draw semi-transparent textures using this with a value of 1.0f in the shader (as above) it draws great.  However, if I then try to fade it out, some colours seem to fade out and some don't  so when it's at 0.0f I'm just left with an odd colour version of the original texture.

Would be grateful if someone could show me how to render these types of textures correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't need to convert the images to non-premultiplied images in the end, I simply kept them in that format and changed the line in my shader to:

```
"gl_FragColor *= "+op+";"+
```

And used....

```
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If they are too dark and have dark outlines, this seems to be caused by color channel being premultiplied by alpha channel. In this case, in parts where texture is very transparent colors are dim. Let's say, if alpha of pixel is 0.9 then premultiplied *RGB* colors will be 90% dimmer than they actually are.

In order to load PNG images without RGB channels being premultiplied by alpha we use 3rd party `PNGDecoder` and then load texture with `glTexImage2D()`. You can get `PNGDecoder` library to decode PNG from here: http://twl.l33tlabs.org/#downloads

Comment: Hi @keaukraine - many thanks for the comment! However, I don't quite understand.  Why do I need to download PNGDecoder?  Are you saying that without it, there is no way to work with semi-transparent textures in Android?  I would prefer if at all possible to do this without downloading anything exta (eg, just by altering my code) I assume this is possible as the bitmap displays OK when using surfaceview, just not with openGL - ..... please if you could elaborate, that would be great - thanks!

Comment: Android `Bitmap` class always premultiplies colors by alpha channel. That's why we had to use `PNGDecoder`.

Comment: Thanks @keaukraine, do you know of any way to do this without using any third party libraries?  Have you used this decoder?  Does this mean that there will be 3 x the memory used?  It seems very similar to a method I just discovered which manually decodes the bitmap, but this method isn't very memory-efficient, how does this compare, memory effient-wise?  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If it was possible we'd use stock Android classes. But it is not. That's why we use 3rd party library. Memory allocation is OK, however I haven't performed any exact measurements. You can find official responses from Google regarding this issue here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/uqbDPmP4L8o